# Shiny app executable with latex and pandoc

Tags: r, batch-file, shiny

I'm currently developing a shiny app that I want to install in different computers that currently doesn't have R, LaTex and pandoc install. I found this blog https://www.r-bloggers.com/deploying-desktop-apps-with-r/ where it is explain how to do this. I followed all their instructions and it work great until I generate some pdf that I wrote with `knitr`. The error I get is:

```
Warning: Error in htmlwidgets::saveWidget: Saving a widget with selfcontained = TRUE requires pandoc. For details see:
https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/PANDOC.md
```

which I interpret as you don't have Pandoc, and I will probably get the same for LaTex if the code gets there.

I know I have to install portable MikTex and portable pandoc in the same folder I have the shiny app and the portable R and Chrome, so I downloaded from  here https://miktex.org/portable and here https://github.com/pandoc-extras/pandoc-portable and install theme. But this did not work

Reading the R blogger and the other webpage cited there I know I have to change somewhere in the code, maybe the `.bat` or  in `R` or in some file of MikTex and pandoc, the direction that `R` is going to use but I just have no idea how to do this.

The `.bat` file currently has:

```
SET ROPTS=--no-save --no-environ --no-init-file --no-restore --no-Rconsole
R-Portable\App\R-Portable\bin\Rscript.exe %ROPTS% runShinyApp.R 1> ShinyApp.log 2>&1
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm no windows or R dev but it sounds like you should include the portion of your `.bat` file that attempts to install pandoc in your post

Comment: there is no portion in my `.bat` that attempts to install pandoc I have no idea how to do that, ill post the file any way but its exactly to the one describe in the R blogger

Comment: Did you read the [pandoc readme](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/PANDOC.md) that the error message gave you? I was able to find how to install pandoc in about 8 different ways in their installation doc.

Comment: The problem is not installing pandoc, which I have. The problem is that R is not detecting portable pandoc.

Comment: Have you tried to set the path to pandoc as a relative path in the PATH variable ?

Comment: e.g. in your script `runShinyApp.R`, add at the first line `Sys.setenv(PATH="path/to/pandoc")` where `path/to/pandoc` is the relative path to pandoc.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent  I thought of that but didn´t know how. Just did it and I keep getting the same mistake. I think the problem is that `Sys.setenv` does not directly  say to R that that's the path to pandoc i just sets a path for something (I think).

Comment: @alejandroandrade I don't think so. R searches for pandoc in the PATH variable.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Ok but anyway i'm getting the same mistake

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent this worked  `Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC=path/to/pandox)` almost what you said.

Comment: Maybe the relative path does not work. I would try something like: `pandoc <- file.path(getwd(), "path/to/pandocFolder")` and then `Sys.setenv(PATH=pandoc)`.

Comment: I didn't see your latest comment when I posted mine. Nice !